# Not Execute a statement depending on input value

Tags: sparql

I'm trying to use SPARQL to provide queries as a part of an application, In this example, the "%s" will be replaced automatically (using java) by the {Name, Type, Value} values in order to find a datapoint which matches those criteria. So far this does work, however, I want it to allow Value to be empty, thus allowing queries on only Name and Type. Is there a way to not execute the last statement:

```
     ?PropertyClass :propertyValue "%s"^^xsd:string .    #Limit Value
```

which limits the results according to the Value criterion if "Value" is empty ? Or do I have to create a seperate query for 2 inputs only?

```
#Query for Primitive Properties
#The inputs in order are : {Name, Type, Value}  
SELECT distinct ?dpt WHERE {

?dpt rdfs:subClassOf :Datapoint_Type .
?dpt rdfs:subClassOf ?sc1 . 

?sc1 owl:onProperty :hasProperty  .#Limit to subclasses that represent a property
?sc1 owl:allValuesFrom  ?PropertyClass .
?PropertyClass :propertyTypeName "PropertyPrimitiveType"^^xsd:string . #limit ot properties that are of Primitive Types

?PropertyClass rdfs:label "%s"^^xsd:string .    #Limit Name
?PropertyClass :propertyType "%s"^^xsd:string   .   #Limit Type
?PropertyClass :propertyValue "%s"^^xsd:string .    #Limit Value
}
```

Comment: What happens if s has a quotation mark in it?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean ? Do you mean what currently Happens or what should happen etc?

Comment: You haven't mentioned what library you're using, or how you're substituting values in.  I don't think that it's the source of your problem, but you may have a possible SPARQL injection problem.  E.g., when you do: `"%s"^^xsd:string`, if `s` has a `"` in it, you could end up with `"foo"bar"^^xsd:string`, which is malformed.

Comment: Oh, I understand. The thing is, the java part will be handled by another person so I think he/she will have to validate the data and set up the libraries. I'm working on the SPARQL part of the problem only